# Error "Msg 10054, level 20, State 0, Line 0" with SQL Server in Docker

Tags: sql-server, docker

I've set up several docker containers in my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS machine. All of them have in common the same [container image](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-linux/).

It works pretty well, but some users have reported me a common issue when attempting a long-lasting query and about a minute after it execution, they get an error message:

> Mens. 10054, Nivel 20, Estado 0, Línea 0
>   Error en el nivel del transporte al recibir los resultados del servidor. 
>   (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto.)

The error message is translated into English is:

> Msg 10054, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
>   Error in transport level when receiving server results. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The interruption of an existing connection has been forced by the remote host.)

Is there something I can modify under their configuration?

PS: I've noticed that in server's properties Connection > Remote servers connections > I've "Permitir conexiones remotas con este servidor checked", having 0 seconds (no wait time) of waittime.

*EDIT*

I attach one container's configuration snapshots:

[image: General configuration]

[image: Memory configuration]

[image: Processors' configuration]

[image: Connections' configuration]

[image: Database configuration. Current values omitted (they're the same).]

[image: Advanced configuration]

Omitted the permission config, as I don't think it's relevant.

Comment: Those are a lot of images, but they aren't in English I'm afraid. Stack Overflow is an English speaking community so please keep to English. The full error message is `ens. 10054, Level 20, State 0, Line 0 Error in transport level when receiving server results. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The interruption of an existing connection has been forced by the remote host.)`. This suggests you're losing connection to the server while running a long running query, or you have a connection timeout setting somewhere.

Comment: You could try posting on https://es.stackoverflow.com

Comment: My installation is in spanish, I'm sorry. I understand I'm losing the connecting due to any kind of timeout, but I don't know where this configuration property is (is it docker or mssql's?).

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue by making use of the oficial [MSSQL image from Microsoft](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-linux), as I was using a custom Ubuntu 16.04 LTS + MSSQL packages. All the data was stored within a volume, so the transition from one container to the new was easy.

EDIT:
The previous didn't actually solve the problem. The real issue was that I was querying too much data. Querying an extensive dataset implied a huge RAM consumption, as much as it was permitted. I wasn't limiting it at all, so when reached the maximum amount of RAM available, the OS (dispatcher) would kill the process. The solution has resulted to configure a memory limit.